# How do I pass the data of the jQuery $.getJSON call, so that I can access them in the success function in Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari, jsonp

I try to exchange data using jsonp with jQuery, which works very fine with Chrome, but not with Safari. First I defined the success funktion within the getJSON call, but that did not work with Safari. So now I devided the code into two funkcions. Again, this works fine with Chrome, but not with Safari. Here is my example code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

<script>

function success(data){
      $("#page_content").html(data.reply);
};


function get_data(){
      $.getJSON('http://10.0.0.187:8888/url/here?callback=?', {
      request: 'get_text', value: ' '}, success);
};


$(document).on("pageshow", function(){
      get_data();      
});

</script>
```

I identified, that the error is based on the arguments passed by getJSON to the success function. If I change the arguments from success to success(), it works with Safari, but then I can't pass data to the success funktion any more. Even success(data) does not work. I get an error in both browsers, that data is unknown. So, the version below works in Safari, but without beeing able to access the data of the $.getJSON call. So in this example I just added a static string to the div for test purposes:

```
<script>

function success(data){
      // $("#page_content").html(data.reply);
      $("#page_content").html("this is a test");
};


function get_data(){
      $.getJSON('http://10.0.0.187:8888/url/here?callback=?', {
      request: 'get_text', value: ' '}, success());
};


$(document).on("pageshow", function(){
      get_data();      
});

</script>
```

How do I pass the data of the $.getJSON call, so that I can access them in the success function in Safari?

Comment: Try to put your success function directly inside your getJSON as an anonymous function

Comment: That was my first approach. That did not work and was the reason I separated the functions. Any other ideas?